# Automate SQL Developer connection

Tags: automation, oracle-sqldeveloper, autoit

I'm looking for a way to achieve a simple thing: type *sqldevConnector.exe IP ORACLE_SID Login Passwd*, enter, and you got Sql Developer opened and connected to the specified database.

We already made quite a lot of small connectors like this with autoit, all relevant information being stored in a KeePass database, double clic = connection opened.
But here we are stuck: autoit handle java poorly, there is no command line...

So, anyone got an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Any chance to test it? Free download?

Answer (score 0):

```
Run("sqldevConnector.exe IP ORACLE_SID Login Passwd")
```

This is written assuming that the sqldevConnector.exe accepts those commands.
To check the right syntax, run **sqldevConnector.exe /h** or **sqldevConnector.exe /?**

If sqldevConnector.exe doesnt support commandline login, you would need to do this by using Autoit Window and Control manipulation functions. Check the help file.